# locationManager.location is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I have essentially lifted this code from the internet:

```
//variables
//location manager
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
var currentLocation:CLLocation?

//outlets
@IBOutlet weak var whatTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var whereTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var whenTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func onCreateEventClick(_ sender: Any) {

    let event = CAEvent(eventId: "123777abc", eventName: whatTextField.text, location: currentLocation)
    event.save { (error) in
        //handle event error
        print(error)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() ==  .authorizedAlways){
        determineCurrentLocation()
    }
}


func determineCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    currentLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    // Call stopUpdatingLocation() to stop listening for location updates,
    // other wise this function will be called every time when user location changes.
    // manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print("user latitude = \(currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("user longitude = \(currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Error \(error)")
}
```

And at first I was able to see the location (e.g., not nil.). Now however, it is nil every single time. I have tried changing my simulator's location, and I have confirmed that the app in my simulator is sharing location. I also have added a call to `startUpdatingLocation()` and added the delegate `didUpdateLocations` and noticed that `didUpdateLocationsAny` is not called. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you call locationManager's method startUpdatingLocation()? The best place to start updating location is locationManager's delegate method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .denied, .notDetermined, .restricted:
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: I also don't understand this error. If I start updating the location when the authorization changes, I would have to first setup the location manager. Why would I set up the locationManager if the authorization is not allowed?

Comment: And one more thought: the 'didChangeAuthorizationStatus' method appears to be continuously called a loop. Shouldn't it only be called when the authorization is changed?

Comment: How do you understand that the authorization is not allowed if your location manager is not initialized?

Anyway Apple provides very clear documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service. I usually follow these steps and everything works good.

Comment: If you still have problems with location service, I can share my code that works.

Answer (score 1):

The location is usually not available immediately after it being requested, once you set your object as the delegate, you should implement `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` and set `currentLocation` to the last element of that array.

That method will be called whenever the location is acquired or changes.